# react native : The correct way to use jsx inside accordion native base

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, function

What is the correct way to use jsx inside accordion to
display the variables content in a specific place for each of them (for example i want display the 'elem.Parameters_String' in the left and the 'elem.Sampling_Method_Code' in the right or in bottom.. ).
In my example I use the accordion of native base.
link --> [accordion link](https://docs-v2.nativebase.io/Components.html#accordion-def-headref)

```
elem.Parameters_String,
digumMethods,
elem.Sampling_Method_Code
```

```
import { Container, Header, Content, Accordion } from "native-base";
  const AccordionExample = () => {
  const [execDetailData, setExecDetailData] = useState([]);

    var digumMethods = '      ';
    execDetailData.forEach((elem) => {
      digumMethods =
        digumMethods +
        elem.Parameters_String +
        ':parameters' +
        '\n  ' +
        elem.Sampling_Method_Code +
        '\n  ' +
        '\n  ';
    });

const dataArray = [
   {
        title: 'apple',
        content: digumMethods,
      },
];
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content padder>
          <Accordion dataArray={dataArray}/>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
}
export default AccordionExample;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "specific place" ? Rendering it ? Or change its place in the array ? What is `execDetailData` ? You'll have to be more specific on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: hi , i change my example to explain what i want to achieve .